# how can I edit the size of back ground box size to make it adjust to inside boxes with node.js

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image of web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeQuP.png)

hello I'm making school project for assignment.
but I don't know how to change the size of background grey box to make adjust with inside E-mail, password... etc box.

here's my code which I'm struggling.

```html
{{!-- 회원 가입 페이지 view --}}
<br/><br/>
    <form action="" style-"width: 700px; margin: auto"
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">
        
        <h1>Sign up</h1>
        {{# if hasErrors}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{# each messages}}
                    <p>{{ this }}</p>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        <form action="/user/signup" method="post" style="width: 500px; margin:auto">
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Sign up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you have put everything inside
`<div class="jumbotron">`

Try moving `<div class="jumbotron">` inside `<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">`

You might have to change the `col-md-5` to `col-md-6`

Comment: @심보영, glad to know. Can you accept it as an answer by clicking the tick mark on the left side?